# Is there a way to insert a bookmark into a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, bookmarks

I know you can do this with a Google Doc, but how about a Google Spreadsheet?

I'd like to have a bookmark and then link into that cell of the spreadsheet from an HTML document.

Comment: Please consider to switch the accepted one to this correct one https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116478/3520 using 
> Get link to this cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real way if linking to a cell in Google Spreadsheets (I'm trying to build one using `HTTP GET`, but [I'm stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813699/open-google-spreadsheet-via-google-apps-script) right now), but you can use a little trick I've found [here](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2013/07/how-to-open-a-google-spreadsheet-at-a-specific-row-for-editing/).

> Insert/Comment at a specific cell, and, in that comment "plus someone"
>   - that is, type "+" and then the person's email or name NOTE: you will get a list of people in your domain as soon as you type the "+",
>   filtered as you start typing their name/email the person you "plussed"
>   will get an email with both the contents of the cell and your comment
>   the link in that email will take them DIRECTLY TO THE TARGET CELL with
>   the comment activated.

Add the person you want to send the link to, or yourself to get the link.

Answer (score 10):

In the meantime   Google Sheet added a simple option to do it:

- click the cell  of interest
- right click it and choose "Get link to this cell"

[image: annotated screen shot]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Google-Sheets-when-Im-linking-to-the-page-itself-how-can-I-use-relative-eg-gid-0-range-B10-urls-instead

Comment: This is helpful, but isn't quite a complete answer to the question since this link uses a naive cell coordinate, not the kind of bookmark other Google Docs can have that can *follow a cell and continue to point to the right target* even if its coordinates change.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution:

1. Create a named range (that is the anchorage) at the calling cell
2. Right click and choose *Link*
3. Select the named range in this sheet
4. Choose the named range

... but it works

Answer (score 1):

But in **view mode** it will not possible so you can easily add **&range=50:50** at the **end** of your **url** that will bookmarked line 50 for you.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful for my purpose - just wanted to create a bookmark that would open a Google Sheet at a specific line. This solves that problem!